# Procesar grandes archivos CSV

Tags: php, csv

Buen día gente, tengo una consulta para hacerles. Debo subir y procesar grandes archivos CSV con muchos registros. Actualmente se están subiendo y procesando vía AJAX pero se cuelga el explorador mientras en el servidor se ejecuta correctamente pero no da una respuesta de como término. Es un proceso que lo desarrollo alguien hace mucho es PHP puro, no utiliza framework.

Se les ocurre algo para mejorar este proceso? yo tenia pensado hacerlo por background y que vaya logueando cuando empieza y termina.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Sin conocer más detalles del contexto y del alcance de lo que quieres hacer es difícil dar una respuesta definitiva. De entrada, si es un archivo muy grande es mejor tenerlo y leerlo en/desde el servidor. Si son archivos que tienes que subir solamente tú, lo mejor sería ponerlos en el servidor usando SFTP.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano por tu respuesta, al subir el archivo al servidor php lo procesa y va insertando los registros en una base de datos. El explorador web se cuelga y no recibe respuesta del servidor cuando termina de procesarlo.

Comment: Subes un archivo por ajax y el servidor no responderá nada hasta que termine de procesarlo? ¿De qué tamaño de CSV estamos hablando?

Comment: El tamaño del CSV es de 3,10 MB, aprox. de 77554 registros pero hay veces que pesa más. El servidor termina de procesarlo pero no me devuelve una respuesta y el explorador sigue colgado. Con archivos más pequeños utilizando el mismo proceso me da una respuesta el servidor que se procesaron xx registros.

Comment: Te dejo un print de la respuesta que me devuelve el servidor cuando son pocos registros.
http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah311/mauritosuarez/Captura_zpsha2mr3ah.jpg

Comment: @MauroSuarez Hace tiempo implementé una solución para ese problema. Si no es tarde (año y tres meses después de preguntar) para describirla como respuesta puedo ofrecerla (sin código porque son muchas líneas)

Answer (score 1):

También puedes modificar tu js
Si estás ocupando jQuery.ajax()
En los parámetros de configuración puedes aumentar el tiempo de espera

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 30000 // sets timeout to 30 seconds
});
```

Documentación: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Gracias user32962, voy a probar con el timeout de ajax y comentaré aquí los resultados.

Answer (score 0):

hola hay varias soluciones para eso:

*debes aumentar las cabeceras de tamaño en el script de php que procesa los datos y también donde sube el archivo.
set_time_limit(0);
este lo colocas en la primera linea del archivo.

*También si tienes acceso a tu server aumentar los timepos maximo de carga de archivos en el archivo php.ini , aca te dice como https://clouding.io/kb/aumentar-el-limite-de-upload-en-php/

*también hay una opcioin desde el archivo .htaccess, este no lo he probado

Comment: Hola andrws, tiene puesto el set_time_limit (0) y el máximo de carga de archivos. Al archivo lo sube perfecto vía AJAX, luego devuelve una respuesta diciendo el archivo se subió exitosamente y un botón para procesar dicho archivo; cuando haces clic en el botón procesar ahí se cuelga... en el servidor se insertan los registros correctamente en la tabla pero no devuelve la respuesta al explorador.

Comment: Te dejo un print de la respuesta del servidor cuando son pocos registros.
http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah311/mauritosuarez/Captura_zpsha2mr3ah.jpg
Ya cuando son muchos registros 77554 aprox. ahi no obtengo respuesta cuando el servidor termina de procesar el archivo

Answer (score 0):

### ¿De qué lado es mejor?

Es una pregunta que es necesario hacerse a veces, cuando hablamos de JS (Ajax y jQuery incluidos) y de PHP.

Como ya sabemos, todo lo que es Javascript funciona del lado del cliente, mientras que PHP funciona del lado del servidor.

En el caso de archivos grandes, la lectura y manejo de sus datos es más rápida y segura si lo hacemos del lado del servidor. Luego si queremos usar Javascript, jQuery o Ajax para actualizar algo en el DOM, podemos combinar las dos estrategias.

Por experiencia, a veces sucede que uno se encuentra bloqueado en alguna parte de un programa, cuando esto ocurre conviene preguntarse *¿estoy enfocando las cosas del lado correcto?,  ¿no sería conveniente cambiar de lado?*

Aunque, como decía en un comentario, todo depende del contexto, del alcance de la aplicación, de quienes la vayan a usar, etc., en un caso como este yo no dudaría en trabajar mi CSV del lado del servidor.

Además, **¡la rueda ya está inventada!** si optamos por esta opción, ya que existe una Clase de PHP que se encarga de hacerlo casi todo.

Me refiero a CSVReader, que se puede obtener en [esta dirección de PhpClasses.org](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/2530-PHP-Parse-and-display-uploaded-CSV-files.html#information):

> This is a class that can be used to parse CSV (Comma Separated Values)
>   files.
>
> The class can also handle CSV files uploaded to a Web server using
>   forms.
>
> The parsed files can be outputted as an HTML table.
>
> ---
>
> Esta es una clase que puede ser usada para leer un CSV (archivo
>   separado por comas). La clase puede también manejar la subida de
>   archivos a un servidor web mediante un formulario. Los archivos
>   subidos pueden ser presentados como una tabla HTML.
>   * O de otra forma que querramos, añadiendo a la misma clase métodos suplementarios.

Teniendo nuestra clase, que no es otra cosa que un archivo php que podemos descargar en la dirección indicada más arriba, podemos subir y leer cualquier archivo usando un fragmento de código como este:

```
<?php 
include_once('csvImp.class.php'); 
$csv = new csvImp(); 
 if (isset($_GET['action'])){ 
     $action=$_GET['action']; 
     if($action = 'upload'){ 
           $csv->fileUpload(); 
     } 
     if($action = 'form'){?> 
<form method="post" action="csv.php?action=upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
         <input type="file" name="txtfile"><br> 
         <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
         </form> 
       <?php } 
} 
?>
```

Como ven:

- teniendo un archivo llamado `csv.php` con un formulario para obtener nuestro csv de nuestro entorno local
- se incluye la clase (se supone que la tenemos en nuestro servidor): `include_once('csvImp.class.php');`
- se invoca al método `fileUpload()` de la clase el cual se encarga de leer el archivo y de presentarlo en forma de tabla

Si queremos darle otro uso al csv, simplemente podemos añadir otro método a la clase que hago lo que necesitemos.

Dejo esta respuesta como otra posibilidad, tratando de abrir un poco más el horizonte :)

Entonces... **¿de qué lado es mejor?** That is the question!

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, como el proceso ya estaba desarrollado, tanto la subida del archivo, devuelve un respuesta que se subio ok + un boton para procesarlo... estaba desarrollado en ajax para que quede más bonito con un relojito girando y devolvia una respuesta con los registros procesados.. pero el proceso de insertar en las tablas esta del lado del servidor. Voy a revisar esta clase que me indicas también para tener otra alternativa, ya que tendría que cambiar el actual funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas dos cosas:

- Tu llamada AJAX debe ser [async](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) para que no se "cuelgue" el explorador.
- Tu servidor está tardando mucho en procesar la respuesta y varios elementos pueden estar enviando timeout; el procesador PHP ya tiene `set_time_limit` así que puede ser el explorador, usa `timeout` en tu llamada AJAX para agrandar este valor. Finalmente el servidor web puede ser el causante de este timeout, puedes agrandar el timeout del servidor web pero varía si usas IIS, Apache, NginX, etc y si usas proxy en reversa, CGI, FPM, etc.

Te recomiendo que revises la consola del explorador para ver que sucede con el HTTP REQUEST independientemente de lo que ves en tu aplicación para que puedas tomar mejores decisiones.